# How can I use PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow without to go for another line?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I would to write 2 texts in the same line like this: "Something is running... OK!", but I'd like to run something before to print OK in the same line. Code like this:

```
PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("Something is running... ");
// action happen here
PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("OK!");
```

How can I write this texts in the same line? Which command without an implicit "\n" can I use?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `PetrelLogger.NewProgress()`, which comes in two variants. The simplest is just a monitor with a progress bar. The complex one lets you configure processes, which can be cancelled. The returned `IProgress` has a `IProgress.ProgressStatus` text, which you can set while the process is running. This is where you send your texts.

For asynchronous processes there is also PetrelLogger.NewAsyncProgress().

The Ocean documentation says for `NewProgress`:

> Creates a new progress scope. Please remember to put the progress
>   scope inside a using statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you wish in the Message window with PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow. You should consider the progress bar status as previously mentioned.